# identifier "cout" and "cin" is undefined even if iostream and using namespace std exist

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, mingw

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main() {

    string i;  //---> this

    cout << "What you want to search?\n---> ";   //--> and these two
    cin >> i;                                    //--> ...

    return 0;
}
```

I get this error:

```
identifier "cout" is undefined
```

When I try to use `cout` without `using namespace std`. I get this error:

```
namespace "std" has no member "cout"
```

I guess this is not about the `<iostream>` because I get these errors everytime when I try to use `cout` and `cin` in another files. I use VS code. Why do I get these errors? My javascript settings down below. I configured the include path but still no luck

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "C:\\MinGW\\include"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "windowsSdkVersion": "10.0.18362.0",
            "compilerPath": "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.25.28610/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "msvc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Comment: add `#include <string>` as well.

Comment: Do you get the errors from VSCode itself, or when you attempt to build? If you get it when building, then please copy-paste (as text) the full and complete error output into the question itself.

Comment: Although one problem could be that you set the include path for MinGW but use the Microsoft Visual Studio C++ compiler and not the GCC compiler of MinGW. It's never a good idea to mix and match compiler and standard library.

Comment: Is there no compiler error in the header files? Mixing GCC headers with MSVC seems like a bad idea.

Comment: `<unistd.h>` is a POSIX (Unix, Linux, macOS) standard header file. It's generally unavailable on Windows. If you're mixing standard library from one compiler with a different compiler then you will get all kind of weird errors. Fix the configuration to either use MSVC++ *only*, including its standard library, *or* use only the MinGW standard library *and* compiler (`g++`).

Comment: Okay I fixed my problem. I just did mix up my compilers for an accident in VSCode. Thank you guys for helping.